# Combine two select with dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

Is it possible to somehow combine two `<select>` tags into one dropdown, preferably in a way which works fine with Bootstrap or the [Chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugins?

I have clients and client groups. In the form I want them to be combined in one dropdown. It should look like "Multiple Select with Groups" in ChosenJS when you use `<optgroup>` tag.

The problem is that I want different post parameters depending on whether user has selected single client (I need to receive client_id) or client group (I need to receive client_group_id)

So a in trivial case I would make two `<select>` tags with different name attributes, which are mutually exclusive. But it would look much better if they're combined in one dropdown.

The best thing I can think of is to use `<optgroup>`, then in each `<option>` to put something like a `data-type` attribute, then when user selects something I'll manually fill some hidden input type. Seems okay, but maybe there is a better solution?